# Prove that if $x_n > 0$ for all $n$ and $x_n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ then $\frac{1}{x_n} \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

I have been given the above question to prove, I've given it my best shot. Any feedback would be much appreciated.

We are given the following as fact...

"$y_n \rightarrow \infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$" means: for each $M \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that...

$$ n \geq N \implies y_n >M $$

To prove I take the familiar defintion of a limit from the first princibles for all $x_n > 0$ and $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^+$.

$$ n \geq N\implies |x_n-0| < \epsilon $$

$$ n \geq N\implies x_n < \epsilon $$

$$ n \geq N\implies \frac{1}{x_n} > \frac{1}{\epsilon} $$

$$ n \geq N\implies \frac{1}{x_n} > M $$

Which matches the above statement we are told is fact, thus proving $\frac{1}{x_n}$ diverges to infinity if its multiplicative inverse converges to zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is completely correct. For a neat proof, you should start with: "Let $M>0$." and then pick $\epsilon$ such that $1/\epsilon>M$:

Let $M>0$. There exists $N\in\mathbf{N}$ such that $n\geq N$ implies $x_n<\epsilon$. Since $x_n>0$, we have $\frac{1}{x_n}>\frac{1}{\epsilon}>M$, hence $\frac{1}{x_n}\to \infty$.